# Skipping subsequent Github Actions

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have a set of GitHub actions jobs that I want to run conditionally on the results of a web lookup.  However, I don't want these jobs to fail, I just don't want them to run.

What I'm currently kicking around is this but it doesn't seem to work as intended:

```yaml
jobs:
  check-previous-build:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/check-previous-build.yml

  bundle-install:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deps-bundle-install.yml
    secrets: inherit
    needs:
      - check-previous-build
    if: ${{ needs.check_previous_build.outputs.previous_build == 'true'}}
```

and the check job looks like this (a 200 means that the job should skip):

```yaml
- name: Check Previous Build
        id: check_previous_build
        run: |
          sha=$(git show HEAD --format=%T -q)
          url=http://example.com/check?id=${sha}
          echo "Checking $url .."
          status_code=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $url)
          if [[ $status_code -ge 200 && $status_code -le 299 ]]; then
            echo -e "\x1B[32m✅ Build has previously completed  \x1B[0m"
            echo "previous_build=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi
          echo "previous_build=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I feel there is something missing around the `needs.check_previous_build.outputs.previous_build` logic but can't figure out what's up here.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some additional code that's required for getting the outputs of a step as the outputs of a job. Based on [Example: Defining outputs for a job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs#example-defining-outputs-for-a-job), your `check-previous-build.yml` should look like this:

```yaml
name: Check Previous Build

on:
  workflow_call:
    outputs:
      previous_build:
        description: "Status of the job"
        value: ${{ jobs.check-previous-build.outputs.previous_build }}

jobs:
    check-previous-build:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      outputs:
        previous_build: ${{ steps.check-previous-build.outputs.previous_build }}
      steps:
      - name: Check Previous Build
        id: check-previous-build
        run: |
          url=http://example.com/
          status_code=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $url)
          if [[ $status_code -ge 200 && $status_code -le 299 ]]; then
            echo -e "\x1B[32m✅ Build has previously completed  \x1B[0m"
            echo "previous_build=success" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "previous_build=fail" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi
```

The `outputs` object on the job needs to be explicitly defined and tied to the output(s) of a step in that job. Re-usable workflows require a similar treatment, but with the `outputs` object in the `workflow_call` block. See [Using outputs from a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-outputs-from-a-reusable-workflow).

This is more minor, but your conditional statement also needed an `else` block, otherwise the `previous_build` variable was always going to be `false` (or `fail`, in this case).

You had the right idea in the main workflow. I omitted the `${{ }}` syntax in the `if` conditional, which is automatically evaluated as an expression ([About expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#about-expressions)).

`main-workflow.yml`:

```yaml
name: Ed's Workflow

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  check-previous-build:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/check-previous-build.yml

  bundle-install:
    needs: check-previous-build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: needs.check-previous-build.outputs.previous_build == 'success'
    steps:
      - name: deps-bundle-install
        run: echo "${{ needs.check-previous-build.outputs.previous_build }}"
```